# Effect of torch weight_norm when dim = None

Tags: pytorch, weight-initialization

```
torch.nn.utils.weight_norm(module, name='weight', dim=0)
```

When dim = None, g parameter becomes equal to $\|v\|$.

Therefore, $w=g \frac{v}{\|v\|}  = v$.

So, I think there is no effect of weight norm to linear layer.

However, some codes use weight norm with dim = None on linear layer as below.

```
weight_norm(nn.Linear(in_dim, out_dim, bias=bias),dim=None)
```

Is there any reason why use weight_norm with dim = None?

I suspect that the gradient become different, but I don't know exactly.

Comment: What are $w$, $g$, and $v$? Where does that formula come from? Have you taken into account that the [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.utils.weight_norm.html) says "To compute a norm over the entire weight tensor, use `dim=None`."

Comment: The formula came from this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.07868.pdf. $w$ is original parameter. Weight norm decouple $w$ into $g$ and $v$, which $g$ represents scale, and $v$ represents direction. The reason I asked this question is because there is no difference of output between using weight_norm and not using weight_norm when set dim = None.